# $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{7}{3}y^{\frac{4}{7}},y(x_0\neq0)=0$ has a unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{7}{3}y^{\frac{4}{7}},\quad y(x_0\neq0)=0$$
is simply solved with
$$\int y^{-\frac{4}{7}}dy=\frac{7}{3}\int dx\implies y(x)=(x-x_0)^{\frac{7}{3}}.$$

My introductory textbook says this ODE has a unique solution. But as far as I can see, in addition to the one displayed above, also $y(x)=0$ solves the same ODE.

What do I not understand about "unique solution" here, or how am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it doesn't really say this particular initial value problem has a unique solution.  If it does, it is wrong.

You have to look at the "fine print" in the Picard-Lindelöf [Existence and Uniqueness Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).  The right side of the differential equation is not Lipschitz continuous at $y=0$.  That's why uniqueness can fail here.